# Add Runtime Arguments For Command In Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to add runtime arguments to the command ./TCPHost. Preferably to be stored as a variable and input when my makefile is ran.

Can someone explain how to do this.

```
ChatProgram: TCPServer.c
gcc -std=c99 -lpthread -o TCPServer.out TCPServer.c
gcc -std=c99 -lpthread -o TCPHost.out TCPHost.c
gcc -std=c99 -lpthread -o TCPClient.out TCPClient.c
open -a Terminal ./TCPServer.out
open -a Terminal ./TCPHost.out <IP> <HOST>
open -a Terminal ./TCPClient.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Enviroment Variables are loaded automatically by the command line.

Makefile:

```
ifndef IP
$(error IP not defined.)
endif

ifndef HOST
$(error HOST not defined.)
endif

open -a Temrina ./TCPHost.out ${IP} ${HOST}
```

Command line:

```
make IP=192.168.0.1 HOST=bazinga.com
```

Comment: I am getting Makefile:2: *** IP not defined..  Stop.